# Glade interface + Gtk3 style sheet problems

Tags: css, gtk, glade

I am making a graphical user interface containing two progress bars. In glade interface designer the bars look like this: [Glade progress bar view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/didbP.png) but what I am getting on the screen is this: [What I get on screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOU1v.png).

I tried everything from adjusting the width settings of the object in glade as well as trying to determine the width by using a style sheet like this:

```
GtkProgressBar {
    -GtkProgressBar-min-horizontal-bar-height: 14;
    -GtkProgressBar-min-vertical-bar-width: 14;

    padding: 2px;
}
```

but without succes, is there anyone who knows how to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

*EDIT:*

So I reread the documentation this time paying closer attention to the program version.

GTK3 Version: 3.14, Glade Version 3.14.2

according to the GTKprogressbar which i am not allowed to properly link, the The “min-vertical-bar-width” style property should still work. Even though it is not recommended for higher versions. Another added piece of information that might be of use is that I am using this on a raspberry pi, raspbian setup and I believe the GTK is the latest available version for this setup.

Comment: Lots of version-specific issues here. Your version of glade is significantly older than your version of GTK+, as most themes have switched to thin progressbars some time ago. (Note that glade version numbers do not necessarily align with GTK+ version numbers.) Your version of GTK+ is >= 3.20, which have changed the CSS selector names. Try `GtkProgressBar, progressbar` instead (unless you plan on only supporting 3.20 or newer, in which case `progressbar` alone should suffice).

Comment: You'll also need to replace the GtkProgressBar-specific style properties with the standard CSS style properties for this to work with 3.20 or newer (or alongside if you still need 3.18 or older). In the case of `-GtkProgressBar-min-vertical-bar-width`, this is `min-width`. The documentation points all this out.

Comment: I just checked versions<br/>    

Glade version 3.14.2  
GTK3 3.14  

I have now tried  
inline `GtkProgressBar, progressbar{  
 min-width: 14;  
    padding: 2px;  
}`  

and  

inline `GtkProgressBar, progressbar {  
    -GtkProgressBar-min-horizontal-bar-height: 14;  
    -GtkProgressBar-min-vertical-bar-width: 14;  
 min-width: 14;  
    padding: 2px;  
}`  

I have no experience with different versions at all, I now get the warning that: Min-width is not a valid property name(3)  
Does this mean its not supported in my version yet?

Answer (score 0):

i just found something like that:

```
progress, trough {
  min-height: 30px;    
}
```

Comment: The `min-width` will solve. The problem is that Gtk use the more-problems-than-solutions CSS. Fast-memory-eating CSS just adds "ignorance" to programmers which (the programmers) no more know what part of CSS to change... unless they search all source code, again and again, for anything in any different version.